# How can I select the most common item from each category from a pandas table without duplication?

Tags: python, pandas

I make a table and then manipulate some values - one column is categories the other is items associated with the categories. For each category I want to take the most common item represented. However, if an item is more frequently represented in another category, I want to take the next best scoring item. So, given the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#make some data
B = []
z=1
for i in range(1,9):
    z=z*-1
    for j in range(5+z):
        B.append('Item_'+repr(i))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.array(B).reshape(40,1), columns = list("B"))
C = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(10):
        C.append('Cat_'+repr(i))
C = pd.DataFrame(np.array(C).reshape(40,1), columns = list("C"))

#construct and fiddle with dataframe
df = pd.concat([B, C], axis = 1)
df.columns = ['item', 'category']
df.loc[df['item'] == 'Item_8', 'item'] = 'Type_4'
df.loc[36, 'item'] = 'Item_9'
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
      item category
0   Item_1    Cat_1
1   Item_1    Cat_1
2   Item_1    Cat_1
3   Item_1    Cat_1
4   Item_2    Cat_1
5   Item_2    Cat_1
6   Item_2    Cat_1
7   Item_2    Cat_1
8   Item_2    Cat_1
9   Item_2    Cat_1
10  Item_3    Cat_2
11  Item_3    Cat_2
12  Item_3    Cat_2
13  Item_3    Cat_2
```

etc

I then make a table to help visualise the problem.

```
#make a table
tab = df.groupby(['item','category']).size().reset_index(name = 'counts')
print(tab)

     item category  counts
0  Item_1    Cat_1       4
1  Item_2    Cat_1       6
2  Item_3    Cat_2       4
3  Item_4    Cat_2       6
4  Item_4    Cat_4       5
5  Item_5    Cat_3       4
6  Item_6    Cat_3       6
7  Item_7    Cat_4       4
8  Item_9    Cat_4       1
```

So, for category 1 I want to choose the most common, i.e. item 2; category 2 gets item 4 etc. The problem starts at category 4 - here the most common item is 4. But item 4 is already the most common item in category 2 (and is more common in category 2 than in category 4). I don't want any duplicates so I therefore want to take item 7. I also want the combined most common items across the whole list of categories - therefore, as I work thru the table I may need to revisit previous categories.

So results would be:

```
Cat1: item2
Cat2: item4
Cat3: item6
Cat4: item7
```

Comment: please post some data and a desired output too. :) thanks

Comment: Quick question. How will you decide which category gets the item? I.e. If `item1` occurs the most for `Cat1` and `Cat2` how do you decide which category gets to represent `item1`?

Comment: `category 4 - here the most common item is 4` It's not! It's item 8...

Comment: Also, what is category doing here? I don't understand how it's relevant.

Comment: Polkaguy6000 - well that's the point. If item1 occurs in Cat1 & Cat2, it should be associated with which ever Cat it appears in most. If it's a tie I can randomly decide. If it occurs most in Cat1 then I should select the next most common item in Cat2.

Comment: Polkaguy6000 - the category column is just a simplified representation of a problem I'm working on - item is bacterial strains and category is the predicted strain our algorithm makes (the headers are irrelevant).

Comment: Josh Friedlander - sorry there was a typo, if you run the code you'll see there is no item 8, it gets replaced by item4: `df.loc[df['item'] == 'Item_8', 'item'] = 'Type_4'`